# How do you complete the "Phantom Prospect" assignment?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

In my battlelog, it shows the assignment called **Phantom Prospect**.   The last requirement I need to complete is listed as a '?'...The How do I completed this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to "hack" in a secret console in battlelog, but since people have already figured out what you need to do, just follow the instructions on this page:

http://www.bf4blog.com/phantom-prospect-phantom-program-assignment-dog-tag/

"bumpinthenight"