# How do you unlock Phantom Trainee assignment?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

Today I have noticed that you can unlock the assignment Phantom Trainee.   I presume this is along the lines of [this question about the Phantom Prospect assignment.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/155925/18818)

How do I start this assignment (as it still has a `?` on it) and what is required to complete it?

[image]

Comment: Sidenote: even though Naval Strike isn't out yet, you can still work towards the Naval Strike assignments (if you have Premium).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have "Phantom Prospect" assigment unlocked.

At Leaderboard page in Battlelog click on skull icon in left bottom corner of page.

Password is:

> epic dream worlds

Source: [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_4/comments/22c237/passcode_has_been_found_by_tammovic/)

Comment: Tested this and verified it works!

Comment: DANG I WAS BEATEN TO IT lol

Answer (score 8):

**PASSWORD IS OUT! SEE UPDATE**

> Our friends over at Symthic have discovered a few of these items by
> data mining the latest Battlefield 4 files, including an award for the
> mysterious Phantom Trainee assignment, presumably a continuation of
> the “Phantom Prospect” assignment.
>
> Phantom Trainee Assignment:
>
> •Score 200 kills with pistols
>
> •Score 20 kills in a jet
>
> •Get 2x Shotgun Ribbons in a round
>
> •Unlocks Phantom weapon and vehicle camo

With Reference To: [LINK](http://mp1st.com/2014/03/11/battlefield-4-naval-strike-new-assignment-rewards-discovered-phantom-trainee-spotted/#.UyZuV-nNu00) (Go to the link to check out the unlockable dogtags)

> yes, I have and yes, you need to complete phantom prospect before
> initiating phantom trainee

With Reference To: [LINK](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2955064775773121287/)

This guy ,might be right, I believe that you have to unlock the mission [Phantom Prospect](http://www.bf4blog.com/phantom-prospect-phantom-program-assignment-dog-tag/) in order to unlock Phantom trainee.

**BIG UPDATE (FINALLY ANSWERS):**

**Conclusion: The password is "epic dream worlds"**

WHOOHOO PASSWORD IS OUT FINALLY. Watch the clip and ENJOY :)

small print: check out his level its 99 O_O

Answer (score 2):

Criteria
200 Pistol Kills /
20 Attack Jet Kills /
x2 Shotgun Ribbons in a Round /

to Unlock the Phantom Trainee Camo

Passcode not available yet !!!

Comment: do you have any reference or source? and how do you know that this information is legit it may well be fake and misleading. see above for full quote

Answer (score 0):

t['WARSAW_ID_P_XP2_AWARD_GHOST']="PHANTOM TRAINEE"; t['WARSAW_ID_P_XP2_AWARD_GHOST_CRIT1']="Score 200 kills with pistols"; t['WARSAW_ID_P_XP2_AWARD_GHOST_CRIT2']="Score 20 kills in a jet"; t['WARSAW_ID_P_XP2_AWARD_GHOST_CRIT3']="Get 2x Shotgun Ribbons in a round"; t['WARSAW_ID_P_XP2_AWARD_GHOST_DESC']="Unlocks Phantom weapon and vehicle camo";

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Currently this is not available because (I am pretty sure) you have to **unlock the ability** to work towards that assignment first- like in phantom prospect.  Its currently listed as a '?'.   How do you get it off of that '?' ?

Comment: @ZeroStack I've seen this referenced elsewhere, I'm guessing someone found it in the game files.  This doesn't answer the question fully, I am guessing you won't be able to unlock the assignment for completion until next week when the DLC is released.

Answer (score 0):

They have recently updated battlelog so now if you click on the phantom skull it asks you for another passcode. Most likely it will be hidden on one of the maps just like in china rising.